# VLAN on local network; single uplink

Tags: networking, router, vlan

I have a home network. Diagram:

[image: Diagram]

The switches are both TL-SG108E

I have an external line coming in as a fibre, which is connected to a convertor to copper eth. From there, it should connect to the WAN port on my router (DLINK DSL-G256DG).
The FC convertor and the router are both in different locations, on which I have only 1 cable laid out. I've put in 2 switches and connected them via uplink. When no VLANs are configured I'm seeing a lot of ping packet loss.

What I thought, is to create a separate VLAN for the convertor and the WAN port to communicate. All other ports should communicate between themselves.

I have somewhat limited networking knowledge, and I've tried the following:
Used 802.1Q VLAN config:

- Port 1 in each switch (router and convertor)

  - set to **tagged** members of VLAN2
  - removed as members of VLAN1
- Port 2 in each switch (uplink)

  - members both VLAN1 and VLAN2 **untagged**
- All other ports belong to VLAN1 **untagged**

Doesn't work. convertor and router can't communicate.

Please advise on what am I doing wrong. And how should I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commutator 1 (cabinet):

- Port 1 - VLAN ID x untagged
- Port 2 - VLAN ID x tagged, y tagged
- Port 3-6 - VLAN ID y untagged

Commutator 2 (room):

- Port 1 - VLAN ID x untagged
- Port 2 - VLAN ID x tagged, y tagged
- Port 3-7 - VLAN ID y untagged

x and y - two different numbers from 2 to 4095.

Unused ports - VLAN ID = 1

Comment: Doesn't work for some reason. Trying prove-of-concept with 2 laptops. Both connected to port 8 in each switch.
So, ports 2 and 8 belong to VLAN 20 only! port 2 is tagged. port 8 is untagged. No ping between the 2 laptops

Comment: @Maxim_united There is no any equipment attached to port 8 on any commutator in your scheme. I did not say anything about the operation of any devices on these ports and do not bear responsibility for what I did not advise.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain correctly. I've tried exactly what you suggested. I had no access to the internet. So, I made a small test instead - reset all VLAN config; connected 2 laptops to port 8, connected direct link between 2 switches in port2; Then, configured VLAN20 on ports 2 and 8. where port2 is tagged and 8 is untagged. both ports removed from VLAN1. It should've worked as well, no?

Comment: *It should've worked as well, no?* PC1 - commutator 1 (port 2 vlanid 20 untagged) - commutator 1 (port 8 vlanid 20 tagged) - commutator 2 (port 8 vlanid 20 tagged) - commutator 2 (port 2 vlanid 20 untagged) - PC2 ? Yes, it must work. If not, check PVID's, they must be 20 for untagged ports (2) and 1 for tagged ports (8). PS. You do not confuse the 'vlan name' and 'vlan id'?

Comment: The uplink between switches should be untagged? and the hosts' ports tagged? That's the opposite of your original answer, or I did not understand correctly? I didn't change anything in the PVID settings. All are set to 1. I should've set them to something in the full setup as well? Can you pls edit the answer to include if so?  I double checked the name and the IDs. Seems ok.

Comment: No. Uplink is tagged, client ports untagged. Look carefully.

Comment: It works :) Indeed the thing missing was the VPID

Comment: @Maxim_united It's strange that your commutator do not set port VID according to a VLAN on that port (search by "autoassign PVID" option in your commutator settings, maybe it exists)... but if so you must remember that port VID is to be equal to VLAN ID registered on that port as untagged (if there are more than 1 untagged VLAN on it, you will receive traffic from all of them, but all traffic you send will be transferred to VLAN set by port VID only). If no untagged VLANs the port VID is to be set to 1 (it's a reason why you must not use VLAN ID 1 if there are tagged ports).